# How to cancel a requestjs download

Tags: node.js, error-handling, download, request

I've code similar to the following stripped down example

```
const req = request('http://www.my.url.here.com/file.bin') // 80 MB file
const decripher = .... // decipher from nodejs's crypto module
const output = fs.createWriteStream('result.zip');
const archive = archiver('zip', {zlib: { level: 9 } });
archive.pipe(output);

const stream = req
  .pipe(decipher)
  .on('error', (error) => {
    console.error(`Error deciphering file`)
    req.abort() // Does nothing

    decipher.unpipe() // Unpiping to prevent the next step producing a [ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END] error

    stream.end() // End the stream as an error does not end it automatically
  })

archive.append(stream, { name: 'file.bin' });
```

Once an error occurs deciphering the file I don't want to download any more data. But I've noticed that in these scenarios a req.abort() does nothing.

In the end I have a file partially decrypted in the archive but it's still ~80 MBs. i.e. The entire file has been downloaded despite the error (which I setup to fire near the start of the file).

Why would this occur? How can I prevent the entire file from downloading?

Answer (score 0):

You can destroy the underlying socket. You can get the socket in `socket` or `response` event.

```
const req = request(options);
req.on('response', function(response) {
    ....
    res.socket.end(); // or res.socket.destroy();
    ....
});
req.pipe(...);
```

Maybe in your case, modify a bit, this is basically a theory but you can do:

```
const req = request(options);
let sock = null;
req.on('socket', function(socket) {
    sock = socket;
}).on('error', ()=>{
    sock.destroy()//or end();
});

req.pipe(...);
```

Comment: Interesting - I'll give this a shot. Any idea why abort would not end the socket?

Comment: Sorry, honestly I don't know maybe because `abort` MARKS the request not actually aborts it. Please feel free to add the why if you find out.